# Get first value in dict from a list of keys

Tags: python

Let's suppose that I have the following `set`:

```py
labels = set(["foo", "bar"])
```

And I have a `dict` with theses values

```py
d = {
  "foo": "some value",
  "asdf": "another value",
}
```

How can I get the first value of the dictionary based on any value of the set `labels`?

In other words, how can I get the value "some value" from the values of the set?

Comment: What is the expected output? A dict is an unordered data structure so I'm not sure why you'd want to do that

Comment: What do you mean by first value? dict and set are not ordered, even though the dict in the latest versions of python3 is ordered by default.

Comment: The expected output would be "some value", because of the "foo" on the set and on the dict

Comment: what's your expected output if `bar` was to be in `d`?

Comment: Not just `dict`, `set` are also unordered. So you can never be sure what the first value will be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression):

```py
result = next(d[k] for k in labels if k in d)
```

**Upd.** Code above works but it doesn't fit 100%, because it iterates over `labels` and retrieve value of first key, which not always first occurrence.

To get value of first occurrence of any key from `labels` use next code:

```py
result = next(v for k, v in d.items() if k in labels)
```

Comment: maybe add `None` as the second argument to `next` to avoid a `StopIteration` error.

Comment: @flakes, I've thought about that, but decided to leave it like it is, because I don't know exact values and it could cause logical mistakes if actual value will be `None`.

Comment: Just for the sake of evil: `next(filter(None, map(d.get, labels)))` :^)

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in d:
    if key in labels:
        print(d[key])
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
and select the element with 0th index. You may want to wrap this in `try...except` to catch the case where no element is found in the dictionary.

```
labels = set(["foo", "bar"])
d = {
    "foo": "some value",
    "asdf": "another value",
}
print([d[k] for k in labels if k in d][0])
# some value
```

Comment: Would highly suggest using `next` here with a generator expression rather than creating a new list. That would avoid the possible index-out-of-bounds for no matches.

Comment: Also use set notation: `labels = {"foo", "bar"}`